# How do I put a boolean result into a variable in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

If I've got a variable $count with a number in it, is there a one-liner to set a variable to either true or false depending on whether $count = 1?

I thought that

```
$result = ($count -eq 1)
```

would do it, but I end up with a value of "1" or null stored in it (depending on whether it's 1 or not).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: My Mistake - I didn't actually have "1" in that variable.  I had an ArrayList that *looked* like it was the number 1.  Closing this.

Full code:

```
get-acl C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc | select -expand access | where {$_.IdentityReference -eq "SomeACL"} | measure | select -expand count -OutVariable aclCount
$aclFound = ($aclCount –eq 1)
$TodayDate = Get-Date -Format "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
Add-Content f:\myfile.log "$TodayDate $aclFound "
```

Fixed it by putting a [0] after the $aclCount on line 2.
(Obviously the ACL in there was the one I was checking for)

Comment: Did you previously cast **$count** as an integer type? If so, a boolean value assigned to it would be dynamically converted to 0 or 1. What's throwing me is that you say it can end up null, and AFAIK `($count -eq 1)` should never return null. Under what circumstances are you getting a null as the value of **$result**? i.e. what are the values if **$result** and **$count** before you execute this statement?

Comment: Okay, I just saw your edit. However, just the fact that **$result** had some other type in it shouldn't be sufficient to cause the type of a new value assigned to it to be converted (it's the variable's type that should change), unless you actually *cast* **$result** as another type. Did you?

Comment: I've updated with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use an If/Then/Else to do it.

```
If($Count -eq 1){$result = $true}else{$result = $false}
```

Comment: Or shorter: `$result = [bool]($count -eq 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce.

```
PS C:\> $count = 3
PS C:\> $result = ($count -eq 1)
PS C:\> $result
False
PS C:\> $result.GetType().Name
Boolean
```